# Selecting specific tab at opening in the QGIS options dialog

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, widget

I want to open QGIS options dialog (menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd>) programmatically and focus a specific tab.

I saw the `QgisInterface.showOptionsDialog` [class method description](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#afacd29d40e70bfb2f20862819f158c94) :

> virtual void **QgisInterface::showOptionsDialog**     (   QWidget *   parent =
> nullptr,      const QString &     currentPage = QString()     )
>
> Opens the options dialog.
>
> The *currentPage* argument can be used to force the dialog to open at a
> specific page.

but I don't know which value enter for `currentPage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With QGIS [code source investigation](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/options/qgsoptions.cpp#L1326), the *currentPage* values are the Qt object names of the options dialog page widgets.

So, the QGIS options dialog can be opened at specific tabs with :

```py
page_names = [
    "mOptionsPageGeneral",
    "mOptionsPageSystem",
    "mOptionsPageCRS",
    "mOptionsPageDataSources",
    "mOptionsPageRendering",
    "mOptionsPageMapCanvas",
    "mOptionsPageMapTools",
    "mOptionsPageColors",
    "mOptionsPageDigitizing",
    "mOptionsPageComposer",
    "mOptionsPageGDAL",
    "mOptionsPageVariables",
    "mOptionsPageAuth",
    "mOptionsPageNetwork",
    "mOptionsPageLocatorSettings",
    "mOptionsPagePageSettingsEditor",
    "mOptionsPageAcceleration",
]
# to open options dialog on the general tab
iface.showOptionsDialog(currentPage=page_names[0])
```